# Sometimes connect is disabled when I deploy an application with startup task in Azure

Tags: azure

I have an issue that when I deploy a simple web application with startup tasks.  After deploying, when I will click on the instance, then it seems to be disabled, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Is there any specific reason for this? And how can I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole section is all about Remote Desktop connectivity. Not the "Azure Connect". So far I have never seen the "Connect" icon disabled after successfull deployment. If you are experiencing issues make sure:

- You have enabled remote desktop prior you deploy (once configured it
  stays configured, unless you explicitly disable it)
- Your account expiration date has not passed
- Your instance is in "Ready" state
- The certificate used for password encryption has not expired
- Wait a couple of minutes after instance state is "Ready" - there
  might be a slight delay between RDP configuration and actual
  enablement

If you still have issues, try clicking on a Role, not an instance. Then the other 2 options shall be enabled (Enable & Configure). Check their status and change it, if the "Enable" checkbox is not checked. And check the "Configure" for the user account and password.

Comment: yes you are right , i was remaining with remote desktop configuration at the time of deploying..